# Activation of ignite pods seem active but not really activated

Tags: ignite

I installed ignite 2.7.5 (not the latest but I must follow company policy) on my  (3 masters/9 nodes)
I installed using Helm charts **in Persistence mode**.

Cloud-provider: Openstack bare-metal.
ignite works successfully( state=active) when installed in **mode without Persistence**

this is my helm values.yaml

```
# Default values for ignite.
replicaCount: 2

image:
  repository: apacheignite/ignite
  tag: 2.7.5
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

rbac:
  create: true

serviceAccount:
  create: true
  name:

dataStorage:
  config: |-

env:
  OPTION_LIBS: "ignite-kubernetes,ignite-rest-http"
  IGNITE_QUIET: "false"
  IGNITE_WORK_DIR: "/persistence"
  JVM_OPTS: "-Xms1g -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -server"
peerClassLoadingEnabled: false

persistence:
  enabled: true
  persistenceVolume:
    size: 5Gi
    provisioner: kubernetes.io/cinder
    provisionerParameters:
      availability: nova
  walVolume:
    size: 500Mi
    provisioner: kubernetes.io/cinder
    provisionerParameters:
      availability: nova


nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}
```

```
NAME                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP              NODE          NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
ignite-0             1/1     Running   0          17m   10.233.66.59    kube-node-2   <none>           <none>
ignite-1             1/1     Running   0          17m   10.233.81.33    kube-node-3   <none>           <none>
```

my ignite pods  are in running but the image below shows ignite cluster is active and also inactive!.

[image: ignite is not activated even after manual activation - screenshot]

Comment: Why do you think it is not activated?

Comment: in the image I attached, state is inactive.

Comment: Cluster activation will only bump minor topology version (`minorTopVer`) and you are grepping for major versions.

Comment: @alamar alright but why do I see state Active when I go on non-persistent mode?  what is (minor,major)Topver?

Comment: Non-persistent clusters do not require activation.